# How to make nextjs use test env when testing with cypress

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js, cypress

I am trying to tests using `cypress` to test `nextjs` application in docker-compose so there is no `package.json` script. The problem is I have no I idea how to make nextjs use `.env.test` due to i cant use `npm run cypress open NODE_ENV=test`. Is there any workaround ?

Comment: This seems very similar to [your more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71292796/how-to-swap-env-file-for-another-docker-service), which has more details; are they different at all?

Comment: they are different