# How to swap env file for another docker service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cypress

I have a `docker-compose.yml`

```
services:
  nextjs:
    container_name: next_app
    build:
      context: ./
    restart: on-failure
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:9.4.1"
    depends_on:
      - next_app
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://nextjs:3000
    working_dir: /e2e
    volumes:
      - ./e2e:/e2e
```

I want to change `env_file` for next_app from cypress service. I found solution like this

```
cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:9.4.1"
    depends_on:
      - next_app
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://nextjs:3000
    working_dir: /e2e
    volumes:
      - ./e2e:/e2e
    next_app:
      env_file: .env.test
```

But this solution does not work. Is it even possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  In Compose (or Docker, or even more generally in Linux/Unix) there is no way for one container (process) to specify environment variables for another.

You can think of a `docker-compose.yml` file as a set of instructions only for running containers.  If you need a specific set of containers for a specific context – you don't normally need to run Cypress in production, but this is an integration-test setup – it's fine to write a separate Compose file just for that setup.

```yaml
# docker-compose.cypress.yml
# Used only for integration testing
version: '3.8'
services:
  nextjs:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file: .env.test # <-- specific to this test-oriented Compose file
  cypress:
    build: ./e2e
    depends_on:
      - nextjs
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://nextjs:3000
```

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.cypress.yml up --build
```

This can also be a case where using [multiple Compose files together](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) can be a reasonable option.  You can define a "standard" Compose setup that only defines the main service, and then an e2e-test Compose file that adds the Cypress container and the environment settings.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nextjs:
    image: registry.example.com/nextjs:${NEXTJS_TAG:-latest}
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.e2e.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nextjs:
    # These add to the definitions in the base `docker-compose.yml`
    build: .
    env_file: .env.test
  cypress:
    # This is a brand new container for this specific setup
    depends_on: [nextjs]
    et: cetera # copy from question or previous Compose setup
```

```sh
docker-compose \
  -f docker-compose.yml \
  -f docker-compose.e2e.yml \
  up --build
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `cp .env #docker/.env`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).